# Accordion in jQuery is scrolling users up the page abruptly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've attempted to resolve this without any luck. I've put an accordion on my page, and once one section is expanded, the rest are closed, as intended. However, this abruptly causes the page view to reposition and scroll up. Is there is a way to get around this happening?

Note: For demo to work, you need to shrink the window so a vertical scroll exists.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sjek6mx5/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('.tf-expand-trigger').on('click', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

        var expand = $(this).next('.tf-expand-content');

        $('.tf-expand-content').not(expand).slideUp(400).parent('div').removeClass('content-visible');

        $(this).next('.tf-expand-content').slideToggle(400).parent('div').toggleClass('content-visible');

    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="randomBlock">

    <p>
      This is here to help illustrate the page jumping up.
    </p>

</div> 

<div class="productPage-accordion">

  <a class="tf-expand-trigger" href="#0">Description 1</a>

  <div class="tf-expand-content" style="display: block;">

    <div class="description">

      <p>This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. This is the first accordion's content. </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>


<div class="productPage-accordion content">

  <a class="tf-expand-trigger" href="#0">Description 2</a>

  <div class="tf-expand-content">

    <p>This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content. This is the second accordion's content.

  </div>

</div>



<div class="productPage-accordion content">

  <a class="tf-expand-trigger" href="#0">Description 3</a>

  <div class="tf-expand-content">

    <p>This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content. This is the third accordion's content.</p>

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.randomBlock {
  background: #b1b1b1;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
}

/* --------------------------------

Expand and Close SlideToggle Information

-------------------------------- */


.tf-expand {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px auto 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.productPage-accordion {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tf-expand-trigger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 21px 0;
}

.tf-expand-content {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the following line at end of your jQuery click listener:

```
 this.scrollIntoView();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bz3pe9na/6/

Comment: Unfortunately that effect is even more abrupt. Thank you for the suggestion though!